# Function overloading resolution with weak_ptr as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, static-cast, weak-ptr

I have:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{...};

class B : public A
{...}; 

void doCoolStuff(std::weak_ptr<A> obj)
{...}

void doCoolStuff(std::weak_ptr<B> obj)
{
 ...
 doCoolStuff(std::static_pointer_cast<A>(obj.lock())); (1)
}
```

And then in B function:

```
void B::doReallyCoolStuff()
{
 doCoolStuff(std::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this())); (2)
}
```

So problems are:

1. Compiler error: `error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'B *const ' to 'A *'`
2. Compiler error: `error C2668:  ambiguous call to overloaded function`

I don't understand how to resolve either of them, because:

1. I think it's somehow connected with shared_from_this, because this is **const pointer**. But I don't know how to handle this situation without const_cast.
2. I don't know if functions can be overloaded by different types of weak pointers.

Build environment: MSVS 2013 express

Please, help. Thank you

Comment: My bad, sorry, I'm trying to make example of code as simple as I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for problem (2), you can of course overload like this. But the problem is that you're calling the function with the type `std::shared_ptr<B>`. This requires an implicit conversion to a `std::weak_ptr`, and it can convert to both `std::weak_ptr<A>` and `std::weak_ptr<B>`. Both of these are implemented by an implicit conversion constructor inside `std::weak_ptr`, which means none of them is better than the other. Hence the ambiguity.

To solve this, you can specify the type explicitly:

```
void B::doReallyCoolStuff()
{
    doCoolStuff(std::weak_ptr<B>(std::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this())));
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/5BwSYn)

Alternatively, you can provide overloads of `doCoolStuff` taking `std::shared_ptr`.

As the live example above shows, I wasn't able to reproduce issue (1).

Comment: @DoctorMoisha Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. code which one could just copy-paste into a file, build and get the error? Without that, since I can't reproduce it, it's impossible to say if it's an issue with your compiler or something you haven't shown.

Answer (score 2):

You may like to review the arguments to your functions.

Functions only need to accept a smart-pointer if they need to keep the pointer somewhere after return. Otherwise functions should accept references or plain pointers.

According to Herb Sutter in [Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style - Herb Sutter - CppCon 2014](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/tree/master/Presentations/Back%20to%20the%20Basics!%20Essentials%20of%20Modern%20C%2B%2B%20Style%20-%20Herb%20Sutter%20-%20CppCon%202014) functions accepting smart-pointers (by value or by reference) is an anti-pattern, unless those function needs to store, change or let go of a reference:

> - Don’t use owning raw *, new, or delete any more, except rarely inside the implementation details of low-level data structures.
> - Do use non-owning raw * and &, especially for parameters.
> - Don’t copy/assign refcounted smart pointers, including pass-by-value or in loops, unless you really want the semantics they express: altering object lifetime.

Comment: This is a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Casey It's not best answer, but I think it's still an answer, because OP asks how to resolve problems and getting rid of smart-pointers as function arguments is the way to resolve them.